# Получить данные ошибки fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, promise

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с fetch.
Есть такой запрос

```
register = (name, email, password) => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/signup`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, password })
    }).then(res) => {
    return res.ok
        ? res.json()
        : res.json().then((err) => Promise.reject(err));
```

В catch прилетает: *message: "Пользователь с таким email уже зарегистрирован"*
Но мне еще нужно получить статус ошибки. Статус ошибки я получаю, когда в then возвращаю: `Promise.reject(res)`.
Я плохо разбираюсь в fetch, только начала с ним работу. Понимаю, что вопрос глупый, но я хочу разобраться что к чему.

Comment: Передавайте одновременно res и err, например `Promise.reject({res, err})`